# While running ng serve command i'm getting this error

Tags: angular8

### Package.jon file

```
{
  "name": "architectui-angular-free",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular-redux/store": "^9.0.0",
    "@angular/animations": "^7.2.11",
    "@angular/cdk": "^7.3.6",
    "@angular/common": "^7.2.11",
    "@angular/compiler": "^7.2.11",
    "@angular/core": "^7.2.11",
    "@angular/forms": "^7.2.11",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^7.2.11",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^7.2.11",
    "@angular/router": "^7.2.11",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^4.1.1",
    "@ngx-loading-bar/core": "^4.2.0",
    "@ngx-loading-bar/router": "^4.2.0",
    "angular-font-awesome": "^3.1.2",
    "animate-sass": "^0.8.2",
    "bootstrap": "4.3.1",
    "chart.js": "^2.8.0",
    "chartjs-adapter-luxon": "^0.1.1",
    "chartjs-plugin-annotation": "^0.5.7",
    "chartjs-plugin-datalabels": "^0.6.0",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "lodash-es": "^4.17.11",
    "ng-bootstrap": "^1.6.3",
    "ng2-charts": "^2.2.2",
    "ngx-perfect-scrollbar": "^7.2.1",
    "pe7-icon": "^1.0.4",
    "redux": "4.0.0",
    "sass-loader": "^7.0.1",
    "tslib": "^1.9.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.13.9",
    "@angular/cli": "^9.0.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^7.2.11",
    "@angular/language-service": "^7.2.11",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.8.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "~4.5.0",
    "cross-env": "^5.0.5",
    "increase-memory-limit": "^1.0.3",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~3.1.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^2.0.5",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.11.0",
    "typescript": "~3.2.2"
  }
}
```

### ERROR

```
ERROR in ./src/styles.scss (./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/angular-cli-files/plugins/raw-css-loader.js!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??embedded!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--14-3!./src/styles.scss)
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
ValidationError: Invalid options object. Sass Loader has been initialized using an options object that does not match the API schema.
 - options has an unknown property 'includePaths'. These properties are valid:
   object { implementation?, sassOptions?, prependData?, sourceMap?, webpackImporter? }
    at validate (C:\Users\YASH\AppData\Roaming\npm\architectui-angular-free-theme\architectui-angular-free-theme\node_modules\sass-loader\node_modules\schema-utils\dist\validate.js:85:11)
    at Object.loader (C:\Users\YASH\AppData\Roaming\npm\architectui-angular-free-theme\architectui-angular-free-theme\node_modules\sass-loader\dist\index.js:36:28)
ERROR in ./node_modules/font-awesome/scss/font-awesome.scss (./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/angular-cli-files/plugins/raw-css-loader.js!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??embedded!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--14-3!./node_modules/font-awesome/scss/font-awesome.scss)
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
ValidationError: Invalid options object. Sass Loader has been initialized using an options object that does not match the API schema.
 - options has an unknown property 'includePaths'. These properties are valid:
   object { implementation?, sassOptions?, prependData?, sourceMap?, webpackImporter? }
    at validate (C:\Users\YASH\AppData\Roaming\npm\architectui-angular-free-theme\architectui-angular-free-theme\node_modules\sass-loader\node_modules\schema-utils\dist\validate.js:85:11)
    at Object.loader (C:\Users\YASH\AppData\Roaming\npm\architectui-angular-free-theme\architectui-angular-free-theme\node_modules\sass-loader\dist\index.js:36:28)
ERROR in ./src/app/DemoPages/Charts/chartjs/examples/pie-chart/pie-chart.component.scss
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
ValidationError: Invalid options object. Sass Loader has been initialized using an options object that does not match the API schema.
 - options has an unknown property 'includePaths'. These properties are valid:
   object { implementation?, sassOptions?, prependData?, sourceMap?, webpackImporter? }
    at validate (C:\Users\YASH\AppData\Roaming\npm\architectui-angular-free-theme\architectui-angular-free-theme\node_modules\sass-loader\node_modules\schema-utils\dist\validate.js:85:11)
    at Object.loader (C:\Users\YASH\AppData\Roaming\npm\architectui-angular-free-theme\architectui-angular-free-theme\node_modules\sass-loader\dist\index.js:36:28)
ERROR in ./src/app/DemoPages/Charts/chartjs/examples/polar-area-chart/polar-area-chart.component.scss
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
ValidationError: Invalid options object. Sass Loader has been initialized using an options object that does not match the API schema.
 - options has an unknown property 'includePaths'. These properties are valid:
   object { implementation?, sassOptions?, prependData?, sourceMap?, webpackImporter? }
    at validate (C:\Users\YASH\AppData\Roaming\npm\architectui-angular-free-theme\architectui-angular-free-theme\node_modules\sass-loader\node_modules\schema-utils\dist\validate.js:85:11)
    at Object.loader (C:\Users\YASH\AppData\Roaming\npm\architectui-angular-free-theme\architectui-angular-free-theme\node_modules\sass-loader\dist\index.js:36:28)
ERROR in ./src/app/DemoPages/Charts/chartjs/examples/radar-chart/radar-chart.component.scss
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
ValidationError: Invalid options object. Sass Loader has been initialized using an options object that does not match the API schema.
 - options has an unknown property 'includePaths'. These properties are valid:
   object { implementation?, sassOptions?, prependData?, sourceMap?, webpackImporter? }
    at validate (C:\Users\YASH\AppData\Roaming\npm\architectui-angular-free-theme\architectui-angular-free-theme\node_modules\sass-loader\node_modules\schema-utils\dist\validate.js:85:11)
    at Object.loader (C:\Users\YASH\AppData\Roaming\npm\architectui-angular-free-theme\architectui-angular-free-theme\node_modules\sass-loader\dist\index.js:36:28)
ERROR in ./src/app/DemoPages/Charts/chartjs/examples/scatter-chart/scatter-chart.component.scss
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
ValidationError: Invalid options object. Sass Loader has been initialized using an options object that does not match the API schema.
 - options has an unknown property 'includePaths'. These properties are valid:
   object { implementation?, sassOptions?, prependData?, sourceMap?, webpackImporter? }
    at validate (C:\Users\YASH\AppData\Roaming\npm\architectui-angular-free-theme\architectui-angular-free-theme\node_modules\sass-loader\node_modules\schema-utils\dist\validate.js:85:11)
    at Object.loader (C:\Users\YASH\AppData\Roaming\npm\architectui-angular-free-theme\architectui-angular-free-theme\node_modules\sass-loader\dist\index.js:36:28)
```

Comment: What's the question here? Please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and reduce the content to [Minimum](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

May be something wrong in your packages.

Option1: Update all packages.

Option2: Re install all packages. *Delete your `node_modules` folder and run `npm-i` from command-line.*